# QGIS shortest path layer to layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am trying to find a solution using the shortest path calculation.
My end points are within one layer grouped by an id, for example 10 points have id 1, another 3 points id 2 and so on. My start points are in another layer, in this layer the id from the end points is unique, for example First Point has the id 1, second the id 2 and so on. For the network layer I'm using OSM streetlines. It would be cool if the calculation could create shortest path from start point 1 to all endpoints with id 1 and from start point 2 to all end points with id 2.
I created an modeller to set the group id for layer 1:
[image: Modeller]

The start point expression for the shortest path calculation:

geometry(
get_feature_by_id(
layer:= @start_points ,
feature_id:= 1)
)

[image: run Modeller]

Routing from each id of grouped points works fine, but the are all connected to start_point id 1 because of the expression. If i understand the modelling process correctly, the first grouped points will be created and then the shortes path calculation will be startet, then the next grouped points will be createt and so on. So is it possible to modify my expression (instead of feature_id:=1) to get the value of the "ID" attribute from grouped_points layer?

Comment: You had a tag for PyQGIS but have not presented any code so I have removed it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here are expected to ask a question. If you don't answer the questions "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" in your problem statement, it's far more likely that your Question will be closed.